# I got an error KeyError Feature not in dictionay

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

In my code I have imported the needed libraries. Then I have loaded the dataset and created my model and tested and evaluated. The problem is coming in the feature dictionary.

My code is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc

import tensorflow as tf
df = pd.read_csv('life.csv')
dftrain, dfeval = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
y_train = dftrain.pop('Status')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('Status')
print(y_eval.shape)
dftrain.head()
dfeval.shape
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['Country']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['Year', 'Life_expectancy', 'Adult_Mortality', 'infant_deaths',
                   'Alcohol', 'percentage_expenditure', 'Hepatitis_B', 'Measles',
                   'Body_mi', 'under-five_deaths', 'Polio', 'Total_expenditure',
                   'Diphtheria', 'HIV/AIDS', 'GDP', 'Population', 'thinness_1-19_years',
                   'thinness_5-9_years', 'Income_composition_of_resources', 'Schooling']

feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  vocabulary = dftrain[feature_name].unique()  # gets a list of all unique values from given feature column
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))

print(feature_columns)
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=15, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  def input_function():  # inner function, this will be returned
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))  # create tf.data.Dataset object with data and its label
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000)  # randomize order of data
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)  # split dataset into batches of 32 and repeat process for number of epochs
    return ds  # return a batch of the dataset
  return input_function  # return a function object for use

train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)  # here we will call the input_function that was returned to us to get a dataset object we can feed to the model
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(dfeval, y_eval, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
linear_est.train(train_input_fn)  # train
result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)  # get model metrics/stats by testing on tetsing data
```

I solved a previous error which was like this but I can't solve this.
The error I have got is this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-d10467b3dec3> in <module>()
----> 1 linear_est.train(train_input_fn)  # train
      2 result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)  # get model metrics/stats by testing on tetsing data

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    235       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    236         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 237           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    238         else:
    239           raise

ValueError: in converted code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:706 call
        return self.layer(features)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:540 call
        weight_var=weight_var)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2418 _create_weighted_sum
        weight_var=weight_var)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2424 _create_dense_column_weighted_sum
        tensor = column.get_dense_tensor(transformation_cache, state_manager)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2852 get_dense_tensor
        return transformation_cache.get(self, state_manager)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2615 get
        transformed = column.transform_feature(self, state_manager)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2824 transform_feature
        input_tensor = transformation_cache.get(self.key, state_manager)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py:2607 get
        raise ValueError('Feature {} is not in features dictionary.'.format(key))

    ValueError: Feature Body_mi is not in features dictionary.
```

Any help will be much appreciable. I don't know why is it showing this error.

Comment: Can you show the columns present in your `life.csv` file?

Comment: The columns are- **Country Year Status Life expectancy  Adult Mortality infant deaths Alcohol percentage expenditure Hepatitis B Measles   BMI  under-five deaths  Polio Total expenditure Diphtheria   HIV/AIDS GDP Population  thinness  1-19 years  thinness 5-9 years Income composition of resources Schooling**

Comment: So you need to change `'Body_mi'` to `'BMI'`? There is no column `"Body_mi"` in your input data. Looks like some of your other columns will have this problem too.

Comment: By the way, you should edit your question to include these details.

Comment: Country | Year | Status | Life_expectancy | Adult_Mortality | infant_deaths | Alcohol |percentage_expenditure Hepatitis_B | Measles | Body_mi | under-five_deaths | Polio | Total_expenditure | Diphtheria | HIV/AIDS | GDP | Population | thinness_1-19 years | thinness_5-9_years | Income composition of resources | Schooling

Comment: @dspencer the columns I just gave are the ones in the data. I have just separated them by |. I have included this data in the code.